# $http request parent to child controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTTP request in my parent and child controller:

**Parent controller**

```
//Product is a $resource object that return http request as a promise.
Product.getItem()
   .then(function(items) {
      //assign to the scope
      $scope.items = items
})
```

**Child controller**

```
console.log($scope.items) <---get undefined.
```

I know it is undefined because the HTTP request hasn't been made when the page first loads but I am not sure how to resolve the promise in the child controller.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to add a listener to see when it will be loaded or do you want to be able to load it before your page loads?

Comment: I want to add a listener to see when the data is loaded

Comment: @PatrickEvans I can't because I want to use the return data in other child controller. I need to make the request in the parent to different child controller

Comment: Then you should save the data in the service, and have all controllers access the service to get the saved data. Or are you creating the Product $resource within the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres two ways you can tackle this

you can use a listener

```
function checkInit(scopeName, cb){
    var listener = $scope.$watch(scopeName, function(new, old){
        if (typeof new !== 'undefined'){
            cb();
            listener(); //deregister event listener
        }
    })
}
```

Heres a little function for it and to use it

```
checkInit('items', function(){
    //whatever you like
});
```

**Method 2** - Recommended for $http service

You can use promise style sort of thing like this in your parent

```
$scope.items = Product.getItem();
```

this will return a promise which you can use in either your parent or child or both as such

```
$scope.items.then(function(response){
    //whatever you like
})
```

Comment: In your method 2, is there anyway to detect if the promise returns error in the parent controllers? +1

Comment: @FlyingCat, just make a fail callback as you set items: `$scope.items = Product.getItem().fail(failCallbackFunctionHere);`

Comment: It should be catch, not fail I believe. You can also add a finally callback

Comment: If by error FlyingCat meant a thrown error than yea it would be catch. Also, the first suggestion isnt really recommended, for triggerng events, which basically this looks like it is trying to be. $scope.$emit/$broadcast/$on can be used for that

Comment: I put it up there for completeness, not everyone get how promises work at the first instance and it can be somewhat confusing.  The first method is not so great for maintainability but much easier to understand. I've changed it to add "recommended" for method 2 based on your suggestion tho